# Can I resume a failed SVN export?

Tags: svn, export, tortoisesvn

I have a TortoiseSVN client installed in my machine. I am trying to do an export by creating a directory -> right click -> TortoiseSVN -> Export. There is huge data to export and due to intermittent network issues, export gets interrupted at some point. Is it possible to resume the export next time?

Comment: you can always checkout a working copy first and then do an export from the working copy. So if you have interruptions when checking out a working copy you can always update and resume from where you left of. Then when you do an export from the working copy it is as good as an export from the URL.